# JQuery Ajax - Dynamic created input elements want to be able to upload with Ajax submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery file that dynamically creates input elements.  One of the elements is for uploading an image file.  When the user clicks save it will add it to a database via ajax.  I want the ability to be able to upload on the same save click.  I am not able to get the file element to submit.

Below is my jquery:

```
var trcopy;
var editing = 0;
var tdediting = 0;
var editingtrid = 0;
var editingtdcol = 0;
var inputs = ':checked,:selected,:text,textarea,select,:hidden,:checkbox,:file';
var notHidden = ':checked,:selected,:text,textarea,select,:file';

$(document).ready(function(){

// set images for edit and delete 
$(".eimage").attr("src",editImage);
$(".dimage").attr("src",deleteImage);

  // init table
    blankrow = '<tr valign="top" class="inputform"><td></td>';
   for(i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
        // Create input element as per the definition
        //First elements in array are hidden fields
         if(columns[i] == '_fk_PO_Req_ID'){
               input = createInput(i,'');
              blankrow += input;
         }else{
             input = createInput(i,'');
             blankrow += '<td class="ajaxReq" style="text-   align:center;">'+input+'</td>';
         }
      }
      blankrow += '<td><a href="javascript:;" class="'+savebutton+'"><img  src="'+saveImage+'"></a></td></tr>';

   // append blank row at the end of table
    $("."+table).append(blankrow);


    // Add new record
    $("."+savebutton).on("click",function(){
 //     alert('save clicked');

        var validation = 0;

       var $inputs =
       $(document).find("."+table).find(inputs).filter(function() {
        // check if input element is blank ??
        //if($.trim( this.value ) == ""){
//              $(this).addClass("error");
//              validation = 0;
//          }else{
//              $(this).addClass("success");
//          }
        validation = 1;
        return $.trim( this.value );
    });

    var array = $inputs.map(function(){
        console.log(this.value);
        console.log(this);
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    var serialized = $inputs.serialize();
    alert(serialized);
    if(validation == 1){
        ajax(serialized,"save");
    }
});

createInput = function(i,str){
    str = typeof str !== 'undefined' ? str : null;
    //alert(str);
    if(inputType[i] == "text"){
    input = '<input class="input-small" type='+inputType[i]+' name="'+columns[i]+'" placeholder="'+placeholder[i]+'" value="'+str+'" >';
  }else if(inputType[i] == "file"){
    input = '<input class="input-small" type='+inputType[i]+' name="new_receipt" placeholder="'+placeholder[i]+'" value="'+str+'" >';
}else if(inputType[i] == "textarea"){
    input = '<textarea name="'+columns[i]+'" placeholder="'+placeholder[i]+'">'+str+'</textarea>';
}else if(inputType[i] == "hidden"){
    input = '<input type="'+inputType[i]+'" name="'+columns[i]+'" value="'+hiddenVal[i]+'" >';
}else if(inputType[i] == "checkbox"){
    input = '<input type="'+inputType[i]+'" name="'+columns[i]+'" value="'+str+'" >';
}else if(inputType[i] == "select"){
    input = '<select class="input-medium" name="'+columns[i]+'">';
    for(i=0;i<selectOpt.length;i++){
//          console.log(selectOpt[i]);
        selected = "";
        if(str == selectOpt[i])
            selected = "selected";
        input += '<option value="'+selectOpt[i]+'" '+selected+'>'+selectOpt[i]+'</option>';
    }
    input += '</select>';
 }

  return input;
}
ajax = function (params,action){
 // alert(params);
 // alert(action);
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "ajax.php", 
    data : params+"&action="+action,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      switch(action){
        case "save":
            var seclastRow = $("."+table+" tr").length;
        //  alert(response.success);
            if(response.success == 1){
                var html = "";

                html += "<td>"+parseInt(seclastRow - 1)+"</td>";
                for(i=0;i<columns.length;i++){
                    if(columns[i] == '_fk_PO_Req_ID'){
                        html +=  '';
                    }else{
                        html +='<td  style="text-align:center" class="'+columns[i]+'">'+response[columns[i]]+'</td>';
                    }
                }
                html += '<td><a href="javascript:;" id="'+response["id"]+'" class="ajaxEdit"><img src="'+editImage+'"></a> <a href="javascript:;" id="'+response["id"]+'" class="'+deletebutton+'"><img src="'+deleteImage+'"></a></td>';
                // Append new row as a second last row of a table
                $("."+table+" tr").last().before('<tr id="'+response.id+'">'+html+'</tr>');

                if(effect == "slide"){
                    // Little hack to animate TR element smoothly, wrap it in div and replace then again replace with td and tr's ;)
                    $("."+table+" tr:nth-child("+seclastRow+")").find('td')
                     .wrapInner('<div style="display: none;" />')
                     .parent()
                     .find('td > div')
                     .slideDown(700, function(){
                          var $set = $(this);
                          $set.replaceWith($set.contents());
                    });
                }
                else if(effect == "flash"){
                   $("."+table+" tr:nth-child("+seclastRow+")").effect("highlight",{color: '#acfdaa'},100);
                }else
                   $("."+table+" tr:nth-child("+seclastRow+")").effect("highlight",{color: '#acfdaa'},1000);

                // Blank input fields
                  $(document).find("."+table).find(inputs).filter(function() {
                    // check if input element is blank ??
                    this.value = "";
                    $(this).removeClass("success").removeClass("error");
                });
            }
        break;

      }
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Unexpected error, Please try again");
    }
  });
```

}

Comment: You should try to reduce the code posted here to the minimum needed to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upload a file like a regular form field when you use ajax.

There are two solutions for that:

1. Use `FormData`. This will work in modern browswers;
2. Use a jQuery file upload plugin. This is only necessary if you need to support browsers that do not support FormData: Internet Explorer 9 and below.

You can find a nice explanation of the use of `FormData` here on SO: [How to use FormData for ajax file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload)